# Telescoping constructor in Java - why calling constructors in culiminative way instead of always calling the same "final" constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

In Effective Java, Item 2, Joshua Bloch suggests using the Builder DP in oppose to the telescoping constructor. I don't understand why telescoping constructor has to call every single constructor instead of the final one with default values for parameters. Consider his example:

```
public class NutritionFacts {

    private final int servingSize;
    private final int servings;
    private final int calories;
    private final int fat;
    private final int sodium;
    private final int carbohydrate;

    public NutritionFacts(int servingSize, int servings) {
        this(servingSize, servings, 0);
        //this(servingSize, servings, 0,0,0,0);
    }

    public NutritionFacts(int servingSize, int servings, int calories) {
        this(servingSize, servings, calories,0);
    }

    public NutritionFacts(int servingSize, int servings, int calories, int fat) {
        this(servingSize, servings, calories,fat, 0);
    }

    public NutritionFacts(int servingSize, int servings, int calories, int fat, int sodium) {
        this(servingSize, servings, calories,fat, sodium, 0);
    }

    public NutritionFacts(int servingSize, int servings, int calories, int fat, int sodium,int carbohydrate){
        this.servingSize = servingSize;
        this.servings = servings;
        this.fat = fat;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.sodium = sodium;
        this.carbohydrate = carbohydrate;
    }
}
```

In the first constructor, the commented line is my version (calling the final constructor instead of the next one in terms of number of parameters). And the same could be done for other constructors. It seems easier to read so I guess there must be a reason why it is done the other (culiminating) way.

Comment: One possible drawback is that the default values for the arguments are specified in multiple places.

Comment: In other words, what if tomorrow the default for calories will be 100 instead of 0? With the "telescoping" constructor you'll have to change it just in once place.

Comment: If you want to change one of the default values when they are not supplied in the constructor (eG set `sodium` to `4` when it is not supplied as constructor argument), then with the current chaining constructors you would only have to change your `public NutritionFacts(int servingSize, int servings, int calories, int fat)` to `this(servingSize, servings, calories,fat, sodium, 4);`. If you would have every constructor call the one with all the arguments you would need to change that default value in every place.